# .NET COM Server ClassID

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, com

I want to create an out-of-process COM server.

To do this, I have followed these instruction:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/VBExeCOMServer-74ecdb1c

In that example code it is stated that I should choose

```
ClassId As String = "805303FE-B5A6-308D-9E4F-BF500978AEEB" 
InterfaceId As String = "90E0BCEA-7AFA-362A-A75E-6D07C1C6FC4B" 
EventsId As String = "72D3EFB2-0D88-4ba7-A26B-8FFDB92FEBED"
```

When I create a new COM server, should I assign new values for these?

Comment: If you ever plan to distribute it, yes you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation I have found this:

```
' (Please generate new GUIDs when you are writing your own COM server)
' Program ID: VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject
' CLSID_SimpleObject: 3CCB29D4-9466-4f3c-BCB2-F5F0A62C2C3C
' IID__SimpleObject: 5EECE765-6416-467c-8D5E-C227F69E7EB7
' DIID___SimpleObjectEvents: 10C862E3-37E6-4e36-96FE-3106477235F1
'
```

So the GUIDs

```
Public Const ClassId As String _
= "3CCB29D4-9466-4f3c-BCB2-F5F0A62C2C3C"
Public Const InterfaceId As String _
= "5EECE765-6416-467c-8D5E-C227F69E7EB7"
Public Const EventsId As String _
= "10C862E3-37E6-4e36-96FE-3106477235F1"
```

do have to be renewed.